# Multiple sets of multiple fields in a single form with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery plugin for multiple fields from this site: http://vipullimbachiya.com/?p=349

I am trying to have 3 different sets of fields within a single form be displayed in a horizontal column so that when you click "Add more" on one of them, it will add the new fields below the corresponding set of fields.

e.g.

```
|--------------|    |--------------------|   |----------------------|
| Item options |    | Field Ship options |   | Notification options |
|              |    |                    |   |                      |
|--------------|    |--------------------|   |----------------------|

|--------------|    |--------------------|   |----------------------|
| Item options |    | Field Ship options |   | Notification options |
|     #2       |    |      #2            |   |      #2              |
|--------------|    |--------------------|   |----------------------|
```

Here is my current setup... you will see that if you click "add more" on any of them, it will append it directly below the one you clicked "add more" on. This is nice, but I would like a horizontal 3 column layout. Any thoughts?

http://jsfiddle.net/infernooo/TzdEj/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but I can' resist. http://giveupandusetables.com/

Comment: I've tried that, but it looks quite ugly? http://jsfiddle.net/infernooo/rKZ89/2/ see how when there is just one "Item options" and one "Notification options" and you add a new "Field Ship options" in the middle, it doesn't create a new row, so the field sets on either side do not stay at the top but come down to the centre of the column? It would be nice if they stayed at the top as if a new row was created below them... ?

Comment: Define "looks ugly". You applied no styling whatsoever to your example, of course it doesn't look too pretty. For example, there's a `valign` attribute in for `td` and there's `vertical-align` in CSS.

Comment: Are you just looking for something as simple as this? http://jsfiddle.net/TzdEj/3/

Comment: Thank you for that - <tr align="top"> seems to work quite well.

Comment: That looks quite good thanks ingo, but is there a way to stop the submit button from jumping around when you add/remove elements? Obviously it will move down or up when adding or removing elements regardless of if a table is used, but with your solution, it jumps up, down, left and right ;) it's all over the place!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this http://jsfiddle.net/TzdEj/4/. I just added div around the fieldsets and floated them to the left ( and the submit button as well).